# Black screen at Fedora after update to new kernel version

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel

I have a fresh Fedora 24 install running `kernel-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64` and everything works fine. Now I have updated the system by running `dnf update -y` and the kernel was updated to `kernel-4.8.6-201.fc24.x86_64`. As soon as I try to init on the latest kernel I got a black screen and nothing else happen meaning no UI no console. I am not sure what could be happening here and I don't know what info is relevant to post here (so let me know anything you need and I will post here).

I have a nVidia GTX 970 but I haven't installed the official drivers yet (I don't know if I need them at all)

This are the options for the `kernel-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64`:

```
load_video
set gfxpayload=keep
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  92268e23-23f6-4111-95ae-20f5d2d97171
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 92268e23-23f6-4111-95ae-20f5d2d97171
fi
linux16 /vmlinuz-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet 
initrd16 /initramfs-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64.img
```

And this ones for the problematic `kernel-4.8.6-201.fc24.x86_64`:

```
load_video
set gfxpayload=keep
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  92268e23-23f6-4111-95ae-20f5d2d97171
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 92268e23-23f6-4111-95ae-20f5d2d97171
fi
linux16 /vmlinuz-4.8.6-201.fc24.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet 
initrd16 /initramfs-4.8.6-201.fc24.x86_64.img
```

Can any give me some help?

Comment: Disable modesetting...

Comment: use the previous kernel

Comment: @jasonwryan how or where?

Comment: You add an entry to the kernel line on boot (generally `nomodeset` or `nouveau.modeset=0` given your card).